# How to use early printk functionality for ARM64?

Tags: linux, linux-kernel, arm, linux-device-driver, arm64

I am trying to use `early printk` for `arm64` architecture but there is no such functionality.There is something called as `earlycon` in arm64 that replaces `earlyprintk`, but its usage is not known to me. I need to print the messages to serial console before real console is initialized. Is there any way to do that in `arm64` using `earlycon`. I applied a patch called `arm64: Add simple earlyprintk support` to `kernel 3.18` but it did not apply successfully. And what is used in `arm64` instead of `printch`?

Comment: I can give you one example for Nvidia Tegra SoC's. This might give you some pointer. The console parms comes in bootargs in device tree.   http://lxr.free-electrons.com/source/drivers/tty/serial/8250/8250_early.c#L19

Answer (score 0):

One can link the functional uart driver either using device tree chosen node or using boot argument.

Before getting into how to use it, you should check whether the platform UART driver supports EARLYCON. For example, directly copied from [owl-uart.c](https://elixir.bootlin.com/linux/latest/source/drivers/tty/serial/owl-uart.c)

```
static int __init
owl_uart_early_console_setup(struct earlycon_device *device, const char *opt)
{
    if (!device->port.membase)
        return -ENODEV;

    device->con->write = owl_uart_early_console_write;

    return 0;
}
OF_EARLYCON_DECLARE(owl, "actions,owl-uart",
            owl_uart_early_console_setup);
```

Here you can see the UART driver registers it's early console functionality, which will be called by ARCH init code (which runs before start_kernel).

Two options,

- Using DTS entry: Use "stdout-path" option in chosen node to specify the serial/uart driver to use

  ```
  uart3: serial@e0126000 {
      compatible = "actions,s900-uart", "actions,owl-uart";
      reg = <0x0 0xe0126000 0x0 0x2000>;
      interrupts = <GIC_SPI 32 IRQ_TYPE_LEVEL_HIGH>;
      status = "okay";
  };

  aliases {
          serial3 = &uart3;
  };

  chosen {
          stdout-path = "serial3:115200n8";
  };
  ```

Again the example is for Actions SoC from [here](https://elixir.bootlin.com/linux/latest/source/arch/arm64/boot/dts/actions/s700-cubieboard7.dts). With this entry in place, one need to give bootargs as "**earlycon**" either from u-boot or using the same chosen node "bootargs" option.

- Another way is to explicitly specify the driver name using "earlycon" as bootargs like earlyprink. **earlycon=owl-uart,e0126000** will ask the kernel to use the earylconsole definition in UART driver and uses the base address for Virtual and physical address mapping.

You can find more details [here](https://falstaff.agner.ch/2015/10/17/linux-earlyprintkearlycon-support-on-arm/).